# Android custom listView - Personal Appearance

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I want to make custom listView. I am thinking of such a thing.

https://lh5.ggpht.com/ZoKmauiAgpdvK-mdJVycMzB7uzf0jchXAbrk88xN9grUqT2q5VvPdTe1uNBVlMA-gLM

I want to have a different look for each "item".

Comment: Cool. So, what have you tried? What's your question?

Comment: I read some tutorials, but it does not work. I have normal listView and running.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: what is the problem?  what happened when you test this example?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do something like that would be to use a lot of imageviews for the icons and the On/Off switch and then create textviews with custom fonts for the textual stuff (depending on what you'd like to use) and position all of these elements using a RelativeLayout as is described here http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/.

Now, in order to user different icons for different list rows, you'd need to store the information about each row in a SQLite database and using that information you can populate the corresponding imageviews with images you have in your drawable folder so if your user chooses some option which translates into an alarm then you'd have to store his preference in the database and use this to choose the alarm clock image from your drawables folder. It's actually pretty simple.